# Type guard on an object key

Tags: typescript

I would like to express a more strict behavior concerning my object keys in typescript.

```
type UnionType = '1' | '2' | '3'
type TypeGuardedObject = { [key in UnionType]: number }

const exampleObject: TypeGuardedObject = {
  '1': 1,
  '2': 2,
  '3': 3
}

// Is good because '1' is included in my type UnionType
const test1 = exampleObject['1']

// Should be bad because wrong key is a string, therefore, not necessary included
// in my type UnionType, but still passed the build successfully
const wrongKey: string = 'bad string'
const test2 = exampleObject[wrongKey]
```

Is there a way to make my second example not pass the typescript build ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why typescript allows you to index into the object has nothing to do with the union. Under default compiler settings typescript will consider any object as having an index property. The way to top this behavior is to enable the compiler  option `noImplicitAny`. This will surface other erros in your code (I would argue good errors and implicitly typed symbols kill type safety and without this settign you might not even be aware of it).

Comment: Seems better with that, yeah, but I may have a ton of 'good errors' to fix in my code first. Anyway, thanks !

Comment: @Quadear yeah .. but really they are good errors, trust me :D